Automatically kill iOS Live Activity after some time
Is there a way to automatically kill a live activity after some time? Say 8 hours. The issue I have is that I have buttons on my live activity, and after 8 hours they become disabled on the locked screen widget, but the widget will continue being displayed for 4 more hours. For the user it is very confusing.
I'm afraid I would have to create a mess and keep track of all my users activities and send a push notification to kill them after some time, as killing the live activity from the background is completely unreliable.
Is there any better solution?

I also have a problem here. staleDate is not working so live activity stays alive. Did you find a solution?
